# Notifications fired at app start

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-notifications, android-alarms, schedule

I want to make an app that sends **scheduled notifications** every day according to **specific times** inserted by the user.
The problem is that when I launch the app I get one or two notifications randomly and I don't receive them at the set time.

Here is my `setAlarm()` function called when the user clicks a button:

```
public void setAlarm()
{
    String mName = NameFld.getText().toString();
    String mFormat = FormatSpn.getSelectedItem().toString();

    Date date = new Date();
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    Calendar current = new GregorianCalendar();

    current.setTime(date);
    calendar.setTime(date);

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, picker_hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, picker_minute);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    if(current.before(calendar))
    {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }

    medName = mName;    // Used to build the notification (it doesn't matter for now).
    medFormat = mFormat;    // Used to build the notification (it doesn't matter for now).

    long when = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

    Intent intent = new Intent(AddMedicine.this, AlarmReceiver.class);

    final int _id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();   // PendingIntent id.

    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AddMedicine.this, _id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager aManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    aManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when, pIntent);

}
```

And here is my `BroadcastReceiver` class:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String[] data = AddMedicine.getData();  // Used to build the notification (it doesn't matter for now).

    // Notification building.

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setTicker("It's pill time!");
    builder.setContentTitle(data[0]);
    builder.setContentText(data[1]);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    Notification notification = builder.build();


    NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nManager.notify(0, notification);

    Log.i("NOTIFICATION", "The notification has been fired.");   // Used to see if the alarm ha really been received.
}}
```

Can anyone elaborate something to fix this up? Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Try `calendar.before(current)` instead of `current.before(calendar)`. I think that you have those reversed. If your desired time is before now, you need to add a day.

Comment: Yes, I just reversed them. By the way, that's not the problem because I still get notifications at startup :(

P.s. I already added a day: `calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);`.

Comment: You keep asking the same question everyday..

Comment: Fra try [parse](https://parse.com/products/push) push notification. you can schedule notification and it's easy to implement too...